# How to convert a string of ids inside an array to array of ids without string in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have below string

```
ids = ["4,5,6"]
```

when I do

```
ids = ["4,5,6"].split(',')
```

Then I get ids as `[["4,5,6"]]`

can I do something to get ids as `[4, 5, 6]` ?

Comment: Where does `ids` come from in the first place? I would understand `ids = ["4" ,"5", "6"]` or `ids = "4,5,6"` but that string _within_ an array smells like a bug elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to split an array, try to split a string instead:

```
["4,5,6"].first.split(',')
#=> ["4", "5", "6"]
```

After that you can simply convert it to an array of ints:

```
["4", "5", "6"].map(&:to_i)
#=> [4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it. More generic version (if you expect more than one string in the original array e.g.: `["4,5,6", "1,2,3"]`):

```rb
> ["4,5,6"].flat_map{ |i| i.split(',') }.map(&:to_i)
=> [4, 5, 6]
> ["4,5,6", "1,2,3"].flat_map{ |i| i.split(',') }.map(&:to_i)
=> [4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Because `["4,5,6", "1,2,3"].map{ |i| i.split(',') } => [["4", "5", "6"], ["1", "2", "3"]]`

Comment: one could do `["4,5,6", "1,2,3"].map{ |i| i.split(',') }.flatten(1)` but it's discouraged (for example) by RuboCop, not sure why exactly...

Answer (score 1):

My answer appears to be less concise than the accepted one and I'm fairly new to Ruby.
I think that you can use ! to alter the Array in place.

## Problem: Original Array with 1 element as a String

```
ids=["4,5,6"];
```

## Goal: Array with 3 elements of Integers

```
new_ids=[];
```

## Process:

1. Convert the Array to a String
2. Create a new Array where each element is created by the comma ','
3. Convert each element to an Integer
4. Push each Integer Element to the Goal Array

```
new_ids.flatten.each do |i| new_ids.push(i.to_i) end;
```

## Results: Display the New Integer Array

```
new_ids
[4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Good job, spelling out the steps. I recommend to get familiar with map and passing a method into an enumerator. There are often more direct approaches than with `.each`, and you will see a lot of ruby code, you will not understand, if you do not now `.map` `.inject` `.reduct` and stuff like `.map(&:to_i)`

Comment: Thank you @RolandStuder :-D